# Como puedo solucionar #¡DESBORDAMIENTO!

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, vba

Hola con todos tengo un problema cuando hago la formula LET para poder filtrar de una bd a otra hoja, lo que me genera en ves de traerme la tabla es un #¡DESBORDAMIENTO!, por favor si alguien tiene una solución a este problema se lo agradecería

```
=LET(
    _empresa; BDInventario[EMPRESA];
    _proveedor; BDInventario[PROVEEDOR];
    _marca; BDInventario[MARCA];
    _serie; BDInventario[SERIE];
    _modelo; BDInventario[MODELO];
    _ubicacion; BDInventario[UBICACIÓN];
    _estado; BDInventario[ESTADO];
    _resultado;
        SI.ERROR(
            FILTRAR(
                BDInventario;
                ESNUMERO(HALLAR(D2; SI.CONJUNTO(E2=1; _empresa; E2=2; _proveedor; E2=3; _marca; E2=4; _serie; E2=5; _modelo; E2=6; _ubicacion; E2=7; _estado)))
            );
            ""
        );
    _resultado
)
```

Les dejo mi función para que puedan entenderla, muchas gracias por adelantado

Comment: [Cómo corregir un error #DESBORDAMIENTO! erro](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/c%C3%B3mo-corregir-un-error-desbordamiento-error-ffe0f555-b479-4a17-a6e2-ef9cc9ad4023). En cualquier caso, si explicas lo que estás intentado hacer y con unos datos de ejemplo, mejor. Da la sensación de que estás utilizando Excel como base de datos y no es buen programa para ello.

Answer (score 1):

Hola a todos los que lean este post, descubrí que la solución para este tipo de problemas es que si lo estas aplicando sobre una tabla en tu base de datos, conviertas la tabla a rangos y con esto deja de hacer DESBORDAMIENTO, espero le sirva a alguno y gracias si intentaron buscar la solución.